# JavaScript - How to get css zoom level?

Tags: javascript, css, zooming

a simple question. I want to use CSS Zoom level to resize my Site oncklick.

I want to catch the css zoom from "html" element.

CSS

```
html{zoom:1}
```

JavaScript

```
function zoomIn(){
altzoom = document.documentElement.style.zoom;
zoomIn = (altzoom + 0.1);
document.documentElement.style.zoom = zoomIn; 
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick= "zoomIn()">Zoom +</button>
```

If i click on "zoom +" i only get Zoom level of 0.1 so i think i don't get an output from document.documentElement.style.zoom;

result is: zoom: 0.1;

There are an special value to get current css zoom lvl?

I will be happy to fix it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because in your CSS file, the attribute zoom of your element is not set, so the JS can't find a value to put in "altzoom" . Try to put it in your CSS declaration.

Comment: Hi, html{zoom:1} or there are some problems with using html tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t get the zoom level of the style sheet. Well there is a way but that would make things overly complicated. I recommend setting it directly in javascript:

```
document.documentElement.style.zoom = 1;
```

See below, don't forget the  `parseFloat` as it makes sure that the 0.1 is added right. If you want control over the value in your back end code (if there is any) you can also set/get this value on/from an attribute or hidden field.

Off topic: Don't set the variables in your function as global. It doesn't harm now but it's bad practice to have `zoomIn` also as a function name in global scope.

```
function zoomIn(){
    var altzoom = parseFloat(document.documentElement.style.zoom);
    var zoomIn = altzoom + 0.1;
    document.documentElement.style.zoom = zoomIn; 
}
```